# React Native: Getting error "Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ..." when passing inline style prop to component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

From reading other SO questions/answers I understand the solution to this problem (simply add `style` to my component's props object) but I don't understand *why* this is necessary.

Isn't `style` an `IntrinsicAttribute`?! If so, why is it necessary to explicitly define it in my component's props object, like so:

```
export const MyComponent = ({ ...other props, style }) => {
    // Component body redacted for brevity
};
```

Comment: It is not, the error message means you are passing style to a component which doesn't support the style prop.

Comment: Oops! That's probably the silliest noob mistake I've ever made, at least in regards to React Native development. Thanks for clearing that up!